# Escaping numbers when using Go's time.Format

Tags: go, formatting, string-formatting

I'm currently trying to take a `time.Time` object and go and produce a formatted string that happens to include some numbers that I do NOT want to be parsed as a time. For example, consider the following program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now()
    msg := now.Format("Encountered a 502 error on 2006-01-02 15:02 MST") 
    fmt.Println(msg)
}
```

Unfortunately, the text "502" is interpreted as a time here: running this code will produce output like `Encountered a 1112 error on 2018-07-12 9:12 UTC`.

Is there any way to escape the 502 numbers so they aren't interpreted as numbers? E.g. similar to how you can escape the `%` meta-character by using `%%` in languages that implement strftime-style formatting logic?

Or is my only option to just split this up and use two formatting operations instead of one?

```
nowString := now.Format("2006-01-02 15:02 MST")
msg := fmt.Sprintf("Encountered 502 error on %s", nowString)
```

Comment: Format is really just for the time. Is `fmt.Sprintf("Encountered 502 error on %s", now.Format("2006-01-02 15:02 MST"))` so bad?

Comment: @JimB -- it's not really the end of the world if that's what I need to do, but IMO it's a bit clunky. Most string formatting DSLs I've worked with come built-in with some kind of escape mechanism, and it's always mildly surprising to run into one w/o that.

Comment: Except this isn't a general DSL, it's just formatting for times. Go favors simplicity, and for something like this it's trivial to wrap it in your own function if it's called more than once.

Comment: Even if it worked as intended, I would ding the usage in the example on a code review as being an abuse of `Time.Format`. I'd recommend just using it for its intended purpose.

Comment: @JimB -- mind turning your comment into an answer? I'm happy to accept an answer that's just along the lines of "there really is no escape mechanism" since it at least does confirm I haven't missed anything in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no escape for numbers in `time.Format`. The purpose of that method is for formatting time, not for formatting strings in general.

If this is used from multiple locations, the usual solution would be to make a simple function to do the formatting

```
func nowMessage(msg string) string {
    const layout = "2006-01-02 15:02 MST"
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", msg, time.Now().Format(layout))
}
```